# OpenSSL: EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp segfault

Tags: c++, node.js, openssl, node-gyp

Using gdb to try and pinpoint the segfault (not really helping), but I might be passing in wrong arguments. Here is the code and backtrace:

**echd.cc**

```
#include <node.h>
#include <nan.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>

using v8::Handle;
using v8::FunctionTemplate;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;

static const size_t PRIVKEY_SIZE = 32;
static const size_t PUBKEY_SIZE = 65;
static const size_t COMPRESSED_PUBKEY_SIZE = 33;

#define CHECK(cond) do { if (!(cond)) goto error; } while (0)

int derive(const uint8_t* privkey_a, const uint8_t* pubkey_b, uint8_t* shared) {
  int rc = -1;
  int res;
  BIGNUM* pkey_bn = NULL;
  EC_KEY* pkey = NULL;
  bool compressed = false;
  EC_KEY* peerkey = NULL;
  int compressed_y_bit = 0;
  EC_POINT* peerkey_p = NULL;
  const EC_GROUP* peerkey_group = NULL;
  BN_CTX* peerkey_ctx = NULL;
  BIGNUM* peerkey_bn = NULL;
  BIGNUM* peerkey_bn_x = NULL;
  BIGNUM* peerkey_bn_y = NULL;
  EVP_PKEY* evp_pkey = NULL;
  EVP_PKEY* evp_peerkey = NULL;
  EVP_PKEY_CTX* ctx = NULL;
  size_t shared_len = PRIVKEY_SIZE;

  // Private key A.
  CHECK((pkey_bn = BN_bin2bn(privkey_a, PRIVKEY_SIZE, NULL)) != NULL);
  CHECK((pkey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1)) != NULL);
  CHECK(EC_KEY_set_private_key(pkey, pkey_bn) == 1);
  CHECK((evp_pkey = EVP_PKEY_new()) != NULL);
  CHECK(EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY(evp_pkey, pkey) == 1);

  // Public key B.
  CHECK((peerkey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1)) != NULL);
  (pubkey_b[0] == 2 || pubkey_b[0] == 3) ? compressed = true : compressed = false;
  if (compressed) {
    (pubkey_b[0] == 2) ? compressed_y_bit = 0 : compressed_y_bit = 1;
    CHECK((peerkey_group = EC_KEY_get0_group(peerkey)) != NULL);
    CHECK((peerkey_ctx = BN_CTX_new()) != NULL);
    CHECK((peerkey_bn = BN_bin2bn(pubkey_b+1, COMPRESSED_PUBKEY_SIZE, NULL)) != NULL);
    CHECK((EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp(peerkey_group,
                                                 peerkey_p,
                                                 peerkey_bn,
                                                 compressed_y_bit,
                                                 NULL)) != NULL);
    ...
```

**backtrace**

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000012097a3 in EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp ()
#1  0x00007ffff4648446 in derive (privkey_a=0x2214af0 '\004' <repeats 32 times>, " \332+\002", pubkey_b=0x2214ec0 "\003\033\204\305V{\022d@\231]>ժ\272\005e\327\036\030\064`H\031\377\234\027\365\351\325\335\a\217\332+\002", shared=0x222d5d0 " c,\002") at ../ecdh.cc:51
#2  0x00007ffff4648817 in Derive (info=...) at ../ecdh.cc:117
#3  0x00007ffff4647756 in Nan::imp::FunctionCallbackWrapper (info=...) at ../node_modules/nan/nan_callbacks_12_inl.h:176
#4  0x0000000000a94a43 in v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) ()
#5  0x0000000000b0bbec in v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) ()
#6  0x0000000000b0c83f in v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) ()
#7  0x00002b6f5fe042fd in ?? ()
#8  0x00002b6f5fe04241 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007fffffffc610 in ?? ()
#10 0x0000000000000006 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q
Quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `peerkey_p` argument in your call to `EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp()` is `NULL`, whereas it should be an initialized `EC_POINT *`. Add something like this before invoking that function (omitting the checks for the sake of clarity):

```
peerkey_p = EC_POINT_new(peerkey_group);
```

That will get rid of the segfault.

You seem to have another mistake in using `COMPRESSED_PUBKEY_SIZE` equal to `33`. Yes, the total size of the public key is `33` bytes. But after advancing the pointer `pubkey_b` by `1` byte, only `32` bytes remain relevant for the `BN_bin2bn()` function.

Furthermore, the return value of `EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp()` is an int, not a pointer. So instead of comparing it to `NULL`, you should compare it to the success value of `1`.

Comment: My pleasure. Some [NULL checks of function parameters](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/7130) would have helped you as well...